# Load an image in Superuser?

Tags: support, images

I looked at the superuser help but I'm still unable to know how to load a jpg I created with a screenshot to be pasted in Superuser in order to explain myself better

Comment: New users are restricted from putting pictures inline to prevent spam.  You can upload the picture to a sharing site and then embed the link for it in your question. If your picture is valid, a more established user will usually edit your question to put the picture inline.  Once you have more rep points, this will not be an issue for you.

Comment: which is a "sharing site"? and how to "embed" there?

Comment: "which is a sharing site?": http://imgur.com/, http://postimage.org/, http://tinypic.com/, [etc.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=picture+hosting)

Comment: An image sharing site is a site like ImageShack, to which you can upload images and be given a link to that image. You can then put a link to that image in your post. When you do that, it's likely that a member with more reputation (and thus the right to include images) will edit your post to include the image directly.

Comment: @AMDG You don't need to re-create your post on meta. There is a process for migrating posts automatically to the correct site once enoufgh people indicate it should be there. The migratuin should happen on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You should first have some reputations to get rid of some restrictions to be able to post image here. For more info you can see "privileges" in your user page.

[image]

Comment: ok, but that is not my question

Comment: @AMDG your question is answered by the privilege at 10 rep "remove new user restrictions" which means before you have 10 rep you are restricted from posting mutiple links and images.

Comment: is there any hope for the new year? :)

Comment: @AMDG the reputation requirements are not related to the date in any way. With 8 points, you'll soon have the 10 required to post images. As an aside, PNG is a better format for screenshots than JPG.