# voting up without reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I've been voted up 2 times in [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9000/load-an-image-in-superuser) question without getting any reputation. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Meta... The reputation is just copied from the mainsite...

From the [What's Meta?](https://meta.superuser.com/help/whats-meta) help page:

> If you have an account on Super User, you have an account on its meta site.
>
> You do not need to create a separate account for meta; once you are logged in on Super User, you are also logged in and may post on its meta site.
>
> **Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Super User (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.**